# How to have terminal print multi-line ascii text one line at a time?

Tags: terminal, ascii

I would like to have terminal print the words "EtherFluid" in multi-line ASCII format when I start terminal, how can I do this? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7yMa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create multiple lines of `echo` command corresponding to a line of the ascii banner and add it to bashrc if you're using Ubuntu.